# A method that return single words from a String

Tags: java, string

As I mentioned in the title, i want to create a method in java that find each word from a String and print it out.

That is how it (more less) look like:

```
public int findFirstLetter(int pos, String text)
{
    while (pos<text.length())
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(pos))==true&&(pos == 0||Character.isLetter(text.charAt(pos-1))==false)){return pos;}
        pos++;
    }
    return -1;
}
public int findLastLetter(int pos, String text)
{
    while (pos<text.length()){
        if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(pos))==true&&(pos+2>text.length()||Character.isLetter(text.charAt(pos+1))==false)){return pos;}
        pos++;
        if (pos == -1){break;};    
    }
    return -1;
}
public void testString (String text)
{
    int first = findFirstLetter(0,text);
    int last = findLastLetter(0,text);
    String word = "";
    int startWord = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (first!=-1)
    {
        word = text.substring(first, last+1);
        System.out.println("word: "+word);
        startWord = text.indexOf(word)+1;
        first = findFirstLetter(startWord,text);
        if(first == -1){break;}
        last = findLastLetter(first,text);
    }
```

When i provide some String as input to this method, the loop is starting to repeat from the middle and doesn't reach the end. For example, in the last phrases the method is repeating "the loop is" over and over again. Could someone give me some advice in order to find what is wrong?

Comment: Yuck.  Why not just use something like `input.split("\\s+")`, and then iterate the array of words, and print them?

Comment: Note that you probably want to search for the last letter starting at or after the first letter when you declare `last`. And I can't see why `pos==-1` would ever be true in `findLastLetter`.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: Dont describe what your code is dong. Give clear examples that show what you expect and what comes out of it.

Comment: Have you debugged your code or inserted some outputs to console to see the values of `first` and `last`while processing a `text`? This should help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Could very well be homework ... and the hurdle is to not use such methods.

Comment: Do not wirte `==true` or `== false`. `== true` is not needed and `== false` can be replaced by a `!` (not) in front of the expression

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Biegeleisen stated in it's comment, you could use split in order to get the words, put them into an array and loop over it in order to print them. Please note that two Options are provided and you should choose 1 of them. If you're learning Java, the second option is more readable and comprehensible.

```
public void printWords(String s) {

    String [] words = s.split("\\s+"); //Option 1: Tim Biegelsman regex
    String [] words = s.split(" "); //Option 2: if the words are separated by blanks
    for(String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Note also that you could save a line of code in this way:

```
public void printWords(String s) {
    for(String word : s.split(" ")) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```